# How do I get down from the arch mages tower?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I'm now arch mage and I put the key to the quarters in a chest in one if my other houses. My reason being once I use the key I don't usually need it again. Of course I forgot that I haven't used that particular key yet. I was exploring my new quarters and decided to see what was upstairs, apparently that was a mistake. When I went to leave the doors were locked, I needed the key and mine is elsewhere. Is there anyway to get down without killing myself? (I play on the Xbox not PC, please not console commands)

Comment: I don't see why you have to stash keys somewhere else, since they don't have weight.

Comment: Do you have Dragonborn? You _might_ be able to get a dragon to land up there and pick you up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm 90% sure you can fast travel from up there.

Otherwise, if you're facing a key only lock on top of an unsurvivable fall on a console, you can load from a previous save.

Comment: I checked, and you can fast travel from up there. It's just the regular outdoor worldspace.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the become ethereal shout, you can gain temporary invincibility and just jump off the top.

Answer (score 0):

It's outside, so you should be able to fast travel. Otherwise, you should reload to a previous save point.